# How To Let A Program Use All CPU Power In VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, cpu-usage

I'm working on a password list generator program. This program needs to be as fast as possible. But it only uses 13% of CPU:

[image]

What should I do to make it use all CPU power available ?

Comment: 8 Cores. It's Core i7 4770K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously your program is only using one thread and because of this not all cores of your CPU are used.

You have to convert your program into something multithreaded

Comment: Let me test your solution.

Answer (score 5):

Heh. I thought it might be 8 cores. The reason is that your app is running on one thread and therefore only one core is being used. 13% is about 1/8 of 100 :)

If you can split the process up into 8 separate threads, then it will use the other 7 cores.

Comment: Well. It worked like a charm. Splitted the task into 8 parts and it uses 100% cpu. Generating 2GB password list in seconds. Thanks